# Sort an NSArray of strings with custom comparator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have the following array of numbers in strings.

```
    08,
    03,
    11,
    06,
    01,
    09,
    12,
    07,
    02,
    10
```

And I want it to be:

```
    06,
    07,
    08,
    09,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    01,
    02,
    03
```

How can I do this? I was thinking of using a custom comparator like this:

```
NSComparisonResult compare(NSString *numberOne, NSString *numberTwo, void *context)
```

But never used it before.

any help?

Kind regards

***EDIT***

Oké so at the moment I did this.

```
   NSArray *unsortedKeys = [self.sectionedKalender allKeys];

    NSMutableArray *sortedKeys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[unsortedKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)]];
```

This sorts the array from 01 --> 12. These numbers represent my months in my tableview. At the moment is starts in Januari and stops in December. What I want now is that is starts in June and ends in march.

Hope this clears the question a little bit.

Comment: what kinda sorting is this?

Comment: this is not sorting.

Comment: use your custom logic for it...

Comment: How should I to this then?

Comment: Sort it normally first and then reorder the values as needed

Comment: @StefGeelen It would simplify if you described the sort algorithm, it does not make sense to me.

Comment: I've edited my question. Hope it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, write a simple comparison function;

```
NSInteger mySort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = ([num1 intValue]+6)%12;   // (6+6)%12 is 0, so 6 sorts first.
    int v2 = ([num2 intValue]+6)%12;

    if (v1 < v2)      return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2) return NSOrderedDescending;
    else              return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

then just call it using `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
      @"08",@"03",@"11",@"06",@"01",@"09",@"12",@"07",@"02",@"10",nil];

NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingFunction:mySort context:NULL];

NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);

> [06 07 08 09 10 11 12 01 02 03]
```

Comment: Smart solution ! Never been good in math... Thanks for the answer dude, appreciated !